# Incorrect CSS left Margin in ul

Tags: css

I am getting this strange left margin in my  tabs list.

I have not provided any margin. where does it come from ?

here is the screen. The incorrect area is marked in the red box.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have explicitly removed it, that margin is coming from the user agent stylesheet used as the browser default.

If you want it to be removed, you may want to investigate [CSS reset stylesheets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Thanks. But This is a nested Div housing other objects including JQGRID all of which render fine except this tab. the outer most containers just render fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Default Browser Stylesheet.

Try:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or more specific

```
#tabs_container ul.tabz {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or more generous

```
/* Basic Reset; remove margin and padding for every element */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: After Explicitly setting the margin and pading to 0 , the problem still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a css reset to get good results on all browsers.
For example:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/